# Help solving Uncaught Abort on HTML5 Build

Tags: unity, c#, javascript, html5

For some reason there is a Invoke that is triggered when a button is clicked that causes my game to crash. Any idea how I can sort this out?

I have plenty other Invokes and none has given problems. I have the Enable Exceptions option set to None and game works fine inside Unity.

I can give more info on the error if you can point to me to what's relevant.
Thanks so much!

```
Invoking error handler due to
Uncaught abort(145) at Error
    at jsStackTrace (ed63bf36d25f876fa57fb81632b59202.unityweb:8:22380)
    at stackTrace [Object.stackTrace] (ed63bf36d25f876fa57fb81632b59202.unityweb:8:22551)
    at Object.onAbort (https://v6p9d9t4.ssl.hwcdn.net/html/1680115/PowerTheGrid_Level3_v7.2_HTML5/Build/3998187b7e8feaa618a93b293c0e6812.js:4:11065)
```

EDIT: Here is the code generating the error:

```
    public void OnClick()
    {
        if (buyCoal.interactable == true) 
        {            
                trainObject.trainMovementStart();

                if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "Level1" || SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "Level2")
                    Invoke("coal_refill", 6f);

                if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "Level3")
                    Invoke("coal_refill", 12f);

                Money.UseMoney(coalcost);
                buyCoalAudio.Play();
                countdown += 1; //agora é count up
                tipCoalReady = 2;
                buyCoalButtonIndex = 0; //DISABLE COAL Buy Button
                coal_stock_countdown.text = countdown.ToString();
                coaltipCounter += 1;                    
        }
    }

    void coal_refill()
    {
        ThermoElectric.quota += 17.5m;
        Invoke("reactivateBuyCoalButton", 5f);
    }
    void reactivateBuyCoalButton()
    {
        buyCoalButtonIndex = 1;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It would be easier if you were to share the piece of code that is generating the error.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with my unity project and it solved itself, probably because I just rebuilt it twice. I did not do anything with the code. I don't know if building the project was one of the reason why the error go away.

I'm still looking forward to better solutions.

Comment: I have found I sometimes need to reboot my machine before I can make an HTML5 Build.